# Electric fields and intrinsic semiconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics, conductors, insulators

If we apply a electric field to a conductor the charges inside move close or away from the electric field which creates a electric field inside the conductor which cancels out the external electric field so if you put a test charge inside the conductor it will not accelerate,it will move with costant velocity from one side to the other side.

If we apply a electric field to a insulator the electrons are held tightly to the atom so the electrons move a little bit to/from the electric field and the electric field inside the insulator isnt big enough to cancel out the external electric field so if you put a test charge inside the insulator it will accelerate from one side to the other side.

But what happens for semiconductors?A little bit of both?And how can we model this effect?

Comment: Intrinsic semiconductors have free carriers at any temperature above 0K.

Comment: The pictures for the two modes under electric fields in conductors and insulators are distorted. Free electrons in conductors and semiconductors are accelerated by a field and slowed to a constant velocity by scattering. Atomic or molecular orbitsls in all materials are polarized by a field.